# Pushing Notification in app using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio

foreword: I'm making APP that can show everyday COVID-19 diagnosed in Taiwan using Jsoup by click on the button. While button pressed, it sends App notification. I wanna to make it automaticaly push notification, so I use BroadcastReceiver.

To facilitate testing, I added timePicker to let users choose the time to trigger BroadcastReceiver

But the problem now I faced is BroadcastReceiver can do things like Toast.makeText, but it can't push app notification.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.covid19.diagnosed">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- registering the receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyAlarm"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.covid19.diagnosed;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;

import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button1;
    TimePicker timePicker;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initialize(_savedInstanceState);
        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    }
    
    private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {

                _notifications("Hello World","starbust");

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), timePicker.getHour(), timePicker.getMinute(), 0);
                } else {
                    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                }

                BD(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

            }

        });
    }

    public void _notifications(final String _Title, final String _Content) {
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        int notificationId = 1;
        String channelId = "channel-01";
        String channelName = "Channel Name";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
            channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        
        androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.jely)
        .setContentTitle(_Title)
        .setContentText(_Content)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setOngoing(false)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private void BD(long time){
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAlarm.class);

        //creating a pending intent using the intent
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

        //setting the repeating alarm that will be fired every day
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    }

}
```

**MyAlarm.java**

```
package com.covid19.diagnosed;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MainActivity use;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //you can check the log that it is fired
        //Here we are actually not doing anything
        //but you can do any task here that you want to be done at a specific time everyday
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        use._notifications("Today number","C8763");
        Log.d("MyAlarmBelal", "Alarm just fired");
    }
}
```

**Toast.makeText** can work, but **use._notifications** can't.

How should I do?

Comment: You need to create the notification function inside your `BroadcastReceiver`, you cannot use `MainActivity._notificaions()`

Comment: @DarShan May I ask how about solving the problem of `getApplicationContext()` and `context` in **MyAlarm.class**? 
Just like this
`final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);`

[picture](https://reurl.cc/loYvGE).

Comment: @DarShan I hava already done it thanks